# Meteor method giving error

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am new to Meteor. I am trying to call a Meteor.method('addTask') from an event helper and I keep getting the error: "Error invoking Method 'addTask': Method 'addTask' not found [404]". I will put my code below:

```
Template.add_task.events({
'submit .js-emoticon': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    // console.log('clicked');
    // var text = event.target.text.value;  
    // $('#text_display').html(text);
    // $('#text_display').emoticonize();
    Meteor.call("addTask");
}
```

});

And the Meteor.method here:

```
Meteor.methods({
'addTask':function(){
    var task = event.target.text.value;
    Items.insert({
    created:new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US"),
    task:task
    });
    console.log(task);
}
```

});

Both are on the main.js in the client folder. I have tried to put the method on the server/main.js and I get an error: "Error invoking Method 'addTask': Internal server error [500]".

If it is on the client it will log the value of #text to console but on the server it doesn't even do that.

As I said I have been learning Meteor and researched this as the way to do it. I am obviously missing something and can't figure it out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to look at a DOM element from your server code. You need to get that element on the client and then pass it to the method, which you can put in the `/lib` folder for latency compensation if you wish.

Client:

```
Template.add_task.events({
  'submit .js-emoticon': function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var task = event.target.text.value;
    Meteor.call("addTask",task);
  }
});
```

Server:

```
Meteor.methods({
  'addTask':function(task){
    check(task,String);
    Items.insert({ created: new Date(), task: task });
    console.log(task);
  }
});
```

You *never* want to convert your dates to strings when you persist them in mongo. That makes searching on dates impossible.

Comment: @oscar I suggest reading [the guide](http://guide.meteor.com/structure.html), for the current file structure and imports recommendations. Also make sure to `check` the method arguments. :)

Comment: Thank you much. Worked perfect. I see what the issue was.  @DavidWeldon will check out the guide on this. Thanks!